# Image path issue when uploading Laravel 6 project to live server?

Tags: laravel

I uploaded my Laravel 6 blog to a live server. I put the content of the 'public' directory in the "public_html" folder and I created another directory outside the "public_html" where I uploaded the rest of the files and folders.

Everything seems to be working ok, except when I create a new category or post the images are not uploaded. I guess it's a path problem.

I think I need to modify the path in the controller, like here

```
 $category = Image::make($image)->resize(1920,479)->stream();
            Storage::disk('public')->put('category/' . $imagename, $category);
```

Since I no longer have a directory called "public", what should I put there? How do I change this path?

My css and js files were linked like this on localhost:

```
 <link href="{{ asset('public/assets/frontend/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

when I just left out "public/" they were working fine on the live, but if I leave out the "public" in the controller code, it's not working.

Comment: Check your "public" disk settings in config/filesystems.php

Comment: this is it. how should I edit it?

Comment: 'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],